# Is this a good practice to pass EntityRepository object to other EntityRepository object?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

As in questions, I need to merge results from both repositories and I can't do it by SQL.

Is this correct way or maybe I should create service class to handle repositories logic?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not good practice. Use a service object to handle any complex operations between two or more result sets from multiple entity repositories. Your repositories should still contain the queries, but a service object should be responsible for merging or filtering them into one final result set.